# Improving quality of Image

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, imagelibrary

I am new to Python Image Library and hope to get some guidance on repairing an image using the python image library (PIL). In particular, I have an image that looks like this. [image]

I enhanced it using ImageEnhance.Brightness function of PIL and then smoothened and enhanced its edges using the smooth and edge enhance functions of the library, and this is what it looks like now.[image]

For the next step, I am thinking of smoothening the pixels as the image looks pixelated; however, not sure what functions of PIL would help me achieve this.

Further, any additional suggestions on improving the quality of this image would be helpful.

Comment: You could try normalization in a different color space